# Drush 8 / Drupal 8 fatal error class not found exception AccountInterface

Tags: drush

I have a Windows 10 PC, using git-bash as terminal window to run drush. Drush is installed in `c:\users\myname\appdata\roaming\composer\vendor\drush\drush`.

My apache server (using xampp) is on the d drive. When I am in `d:/xampp/htdocs/` I can run drush in the terminal just fine (drush dl honeypot works perfectly). If I cd another level to `d:/xampp/htdocs/dev1` and try to run drush I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\jbcg\core\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 58 Drush
>   command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found
>   in D:\xampp\htdocs\jbcg\core\includes\bootstrap.inc, line 58 PHP Fatal
>   error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\jbcg\core\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 58

If I cd back up a level to `htdocs`, I can execute the command just fine. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: You claim that if you cd into `d:/xampp/htdocs/dev1`, then Drush tries (and fails) to bootstrap a site in `D:\xampp\htdocs\jbcg`.  This does not really make sense. There's not enough info here to diagnose.  You'll first need to figure out which Drupal root Drush is bootstrapping from htdocs; `drush status` will tell you this. Then, you need to figure out why a different Drupal root is being selected when you cd to a child folder. Check for `$options['root']` in a drushrc.php file, site alias usage, etc.; also, run with --debug for more hints about what Drush is doing.

Comment: Sorry, it is jdbg, not dev1. That was a typo. Here is the status:

drush status 
$ drush status
 PHP executable        :  php
 PHP configuration     :  D:\xampp\php\php.ini
 PHP OS                :  WINNT
 Drush version         :  6.0-rc4
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :  C:\Users\james/.drush/d8.local.aliases.drushrc.php

I need to upgrade to drush 8 I believe

Comment: Okay, upgraded to version 8 and it works. What I had done is git checkout 8.x-6.0 which I thought was version 8 but it was version 6. Installing with composer dev-master branch updated to version 8. My bad and thanks for the help.

Comment: Those branches were deleted a long time ago, but someone pushed them back up a while ago (on accident, no doubt). I recently deleted them all again. Sorry for the inconvenience.